# Merge request from a specific commit to another branch

Tags: git, gitlab

I'm looking to create a workflow for my team, using GitLab as a cooperative platform.

I was checking the other topics related to this, but I'm not really sure if the following scenario is possible:

We have 2 branches: the first one is the online version of our application and the other one is the offline version of the app. If we add a feature in the offline version, we will want to take that commit and add it to the online version too.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

If you do a merge request, this is generally from one branch (with *all* its commits) to another.

You might consider a[cherry-pick](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) of one commit to another branch, but that works if you never merge those two branches (or you would end up with a log of duplicate commits).

Merge requests do support [cherry-picking](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/cherry_pick_changes.html#cherry-pick-a-commit) a commit.
You can create a [MR automatically](https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2017/09/05/how-to-automatically-create-a-new-mr-on-gitlab-with-gitlab-ci/), but your script should include a check for relevant commit messages, to determine if an MR is needed (Ie, in your case, if a commit adds a new feature).